# I've been told that Cisco is changing their commands with every IOS, that seems unlikely. Can anyone confirm that?

Tags: cisco, cli

I'm thinking of starting to work on my CCNA since I'm getting a little training in Fortinet and maybe getting sent to certification class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although changes do occur between major releases of IOS, examples being: the addition of EIGPv6, and changes in the crypto key generate command. These commands can also vary based on the allowed feature set and the underlying hardware that is running the IOS image (ISL being one that comes to mind). Understanding that things will change is necessary in any line of work, however Cisco tries to keep the syntax for its commands the same and will give ample warning if they change anything. There is always the tab complete option and ? on actual IOS devices if you ever find yourself not finding the command you are looking for.

TLDR: Cisco will change things as needed (new features, outdated technology) but they aren't pointlessly making it difficult for its users

Comment: Thank you very much David, the way it was portrayed to me it was almost as if they were trying to make it pointlessly difficult. And as I mentioned in the question, that seemed unlikely.

Comment: Often the "difficulty" is in simply not knowing why Cisco changed things.  For instance, the ASA's NAT configuration had a major change between 8.2 and 8.3, and people complained that the new NAT was too difficult and complicated... until they realized how much more functionality there was with the new NAT commands, and now many engineers I work prefer the new NAT configuration to the old.

Answer (score 6):

In general, if you learned IOS 11, you can jump into an IOS 15 device and still feel somewhat at home.

That said, absolutely there are changes between different versions of IOS and even the same version of IOS on different platforms.  There would be no progress if there were no changes and I personally wouldn't want to be running IOS 11 today.

- **New features/commands** are added to provide additional functionality or access to new information.
- **Enahanced features/commands** add additional options to existing features and commands.  An example of this type of enhancement is the improvements to *show running-config** over the years that let a user display parts of the configuration instead of all of it.
- **Deprecated features/commands** are often supported for years before they are phased out entirely.  Most will tell you they are deprecated in some fashion and other commands should be used instead (sometimes this is logged at boot time).
- **Hardware dependent features/commands** will be available or not depending on the hardware.  A prime example would be Cisco's [TDR Cable Diagnostics](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/74231/how-use-time-domain-reflectometer-tdr) feature.  If the hardware doesn't support it, even if the commands are available, they won't work.

However, when you are talking about Cisco more generally, they definitely have a range of operating systems that do not look/feel/act like IOS.  Here is a very brief and non-inclusive list of some of them:

- **CatOS** - common on their earlier chassis based switches, such as the 4000s, 5500s, 6500s and the like, but could be found on other platforms as well (such as the 2980).
- **NX-OS** - the Nexus Operating System which runs on all their new Nexus platforms.  While similar in many respects to IOS, there is enough of a difference to trip someone up if they are not aware of them.
- **Catalyst 1900 OS** - some would say the predecessor to IOS, but even if you had the enterprise version (with access to the CLI rather than just the menu driven interface), the differences are significant.
- **Acquired technology** - many of the acquired technologies by Cisco do not operate like IOS.  As time goes by, they do often try to convert many of these to be more IOS-like in nature.  Or they implement the acquired features into IOS.  One example is the OS run on their wireless controllers, which have not been updated to match IOS.

Comment: I'd argue that NX-OS feels way more like IOS than CatOS does (ugh CatOS)

Comment: Agreed (and have similar feelings to CatOS...although I prefer it to the 1900 OS).  It is that similarity that usually results in people familiar with IOS (and not NX-OS) making mistakes that can create issues.

Comment: Thanks All, if they do send me to the Fortinet training I feel good about continuing on with the Cisco training.

Comment: Not to mention the IOS-XR operating system, having a completely different CLI.